# Why isn't MVC web application reflecting permission additions in a SQL Server based security model

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, security, permissions, authorization

I've built an MVC 5 intranet web app in the company I work for. It's built using windows authentication and impersonates the user of the app.

On the backend, there is a centralized security database which has an employee table, a role table and a bridge table to join both.

There is an MVC view which is basically a datatable with employees and permissions, pivoted. Users connect to the webapp, the webapps reads the username and checks SQL Server to see what permissions they have. Therefore it's very easy for administrators to authorize use of the site with a nice front end.

[image]

Here's the issue - when I assign 'SRPE' permission to myself (which successfully adds the record to the bridge table), I expect to see that change reflected. Effectively this permission, if true, makes MVC return an alternative view for one of the views I've built. Anyway, it doesn't work.

The actual result is that nothing happens, i.e. the same view is being returned. By the way this is all running from VS for now. So by accident I managed to cause an error in the app during some other operation and funnily enough when I fixed the bug and restarted the site, the permission was reflected.

What I don't understand is why the permission isn't reflected during runtime. This design pattern I've used all over. The security class looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using MDMWebApp.Models;

namespace MDMWebApp.Security
{
    public class MenuSecurity
    {

    // DMPA    DMP Admin
    // EIPA    EIP Admin
    // EIPU    EIP User
    // SRPA    Standard Reporting Admin
    // SRPE    Standard Reporting Entity User
    // SRPM    Standard Reporting Master Data Contributer
    // SRPU    Standard Reporting User

    private static SecurityDbContext _context = new SecurityDbContext();

    private vEmployeeRole employeeRole = _context.vEmployeeRoles.SingleOrDefault(er => er.Username == Environment.UserName);
    private bool isOnSystem => employeeRole != null ? true : false;
    private bool isDMPAdmin => employeeRole.DMPA;
    private bool isEIPAdmin => employeeRole.EIPA;
    private bool isEIPUser => employeeRole.EIPU;
    private bool isStandardReportingAdmin => employeeRole.SRPA;
    private bool isStandardReportingEntityUser => employeeRole.SRPE;
    private bool isStandardReportingMasterDataContributer => employeeRole.SRPM;
    private bool isStandardReportingUser => employeeRole.SRPU;

    public bool CanUseSystem
    {
        get { return isOnSystem; }
    }

    public bool DMPAdmin
    {
        get
        {
            return isDMPAdmin;
        }
    }

    public bool EIPAdmin
    {
        get
        {
            return isDMPAdmin || isEIPAdmin;
        }
    }

    public bool CanSeeEIP
    {
        get
        {
            return isDMPAdmin || isEIPAdmin || isEIPUser;
        }
    }

    public bool StandardReportingEntityUser
    {
        get
        {
            return isStandardReportingEntityUser;
        }
    }

    public bool StandardReportingMasterDataContributer
    {
        get
        {
            return isDMPAdmin || isStandardReportingAdmin || isStandardReportingMasterDataContributer;
        }
    }
}
}
```

and controller/action in question:

```
public ActionResult TaskTracker()
    {

        var lastWeekEnding = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7);
        var taskTracker = _context.TaskTracker.Where(d => d.WeekEnding >= lastWeekEnding);
        MenuSecurity ms = new MenuSecurity();

        if (ms.StandardReportingEntityUser)
        {
            return View("TaskTrackerEntity",taskTracker);
        }

        else return View("TaskTracker", taskTracker);
    }
```

Does MVC not execute the action on hitting the appropriate route and then do a fresh retrieval of permissions at action execution time?

Comment: Sounds like caching to me.  Your SecurityDbContext is static... It gets created once, and then shared among all MenuSecurity instances.  Unless you restart the app, or only do updates through that static SecurityDbContext, it won't go back to db for those roles.

Comment: Thanks Mike. With that in mind I’ll try and come up with a workaround.

Comment: It looks like it's up to you.  If you want a single list retrieved once per App Start, then use a static field.  If you want "do a fresh retrieval of permissions at action execution time" then new DbContext() each time.

Answer (score 0):

Finally resolved the issue. By implementing the **using** statement in the MenuSecurity class, the connection was disposed of after each use, thus retrieving fresh records each time. To do this I used an initialization method and called it each time I created a new instance of Menu Security.

Here is the updated class:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using MDMWebApp.Models;

namespace MDMWebApp.Security
{
    public class MenuSecurity
    {

        // DMPA    DMP Admin
        // EIPA    EIP Admin
        // EIPU    EIP User
        // SRPA    Standard Reporting Admin
        // SRPE    Standard Reporting Entity User
        // SRPM    Standard Reporting Master Data Contributer
        // SRPU    Standard Reporting User

        private bool isOnSystem;
        private bool isDMPAdmin;
        private bool isEIPAdmin;
        private bool isEIPUser;
        private bool isStandardReportingAdmin;
        private bool isStandardReportingEntityUser;
        private bool isStandardReportingMasterDataContributer;
        private bool isStandardReportingUser;

        public void Initialize()
        {
            using (var _context = new SecurityDbContext())
            {

                var employeeRole = _context.vEmployeeRoles.SingleOrDefault(er => er.Username == Environment.UserName);
                isOnSystem = employeeRole != null ? true : false;
                isDMPAdmin = employeeRole.DMPA;
                isEIPAdmin = employeeRole.EIPA;
                isEIPUser = employeeRole.EIPU;
                isStandardReportingAdmin = employeeRole.SRPA;
                isStandardReportingEntityUser = employeeRole.SRPE;
                isStandardReportingMasterDataContributer = employeeRole.SRPM;
                isStandardReportingUser = employeeRole.SRPU;
            }
        }

        public bool CanUseSystem
        {
            get { return isOnSystem; }
        }

        public bool DMPAdmin
        {
            get
            {
                return isDMPAdmin;
            }
        }

        public bool EIPAdmin
        {
            get
            {
                return isDMPAdmin || isEIPAdmin;
            }
        }

        public bool CanSeeEIP
        {
            get
            {
                return isDMPAdmin || isEIPAdmin || isEIPUser;
            }
        }

        public bool StandardReportingEntityUser
        {
            get
            {
                return isStandardReportingEntityUser;
            }
        }

        public bool StandardReportingMasterDataContributer
        {
            get
            {
                return isDMPAdmin || isStandardReportingAdmin || isStandardReportingMasterDataContributer;
            }
        }


    }
}
```